# lxde-rc.xml: set keybindings for PgDn

Tags: linux, debian, openbox, lxde

I am using LXDE, and I need to create keybinding for <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> in my `$HOME/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

I already have the necessary code, the only thing missing is the correct description for <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd>:

```
<keybind key="INSERT CODE FOR PAGE DOWN HERE">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <name>amixer</name>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>amixer -c 0 set Master 5- unmute</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Could somebody please advise what is the code for those two keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Openbox documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings#Keys):

> The Key is the name of the key, such as "a", "space", "Escape",
>   "less", or "F1". You can find the name of any key by using the xev
>   command in a terminal, pressing the desired key, and watching the
>   output from xev in the terminal.

To answer your question

```
<keybind key="A-Prior">
```

for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> binding and

```
<keybind key="A-Next">
```

for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> binding.